# Why won't my popups display?

Tags: html, css, jsp, popup

I have another popups using this technique on the same page so it should work and it used to work after some update I did broke the rendering. It used to work but now I have an HTML regression error where an update b0rked old view so now my popups don't display. I have a number of buttons that should activate a popup:
[image]

Pressing search then activates this code

`<input type="button" value="S&ouml;k" onClick="getElementById('popupF').style.display=''">`

which should render this popup

```
<div class="popup" id="popupF" 
<% if(!showSearchF) { %>
style="display: none;"
<% } %>
>
<%@ include file="includes/fullfoljd_fran_sok.jsp" %>
</div>
```

that in its turn is this JSPF fragment that should render on top of this page but nothing appears.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" align="center" class="TB_nb">
  <tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="pusher TB_nb"><h2>Sök person/företag</h2> 
</td>
  <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('popupSokNamn').style.display = 'none';" >X</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<h2 class="pusher">Sök person/företag</h2>
<div id="Vsok">

<div style="text-align: right; width: 100%; padding-right: 5%; padding-top: 5px;">
<span onClick="getElementById('sokF').style.display='', getElementById('bottomA').style.display='none', getElementById('bottomV').style.display='', getElementById('Vsok').style.display='none'" class="link_sm">Visa s&ouml;kformul&auml;r</span>
</div>

</div>

<div id="sokF">

<div style="text-align: right; width: 100%; padding-right: 5%; padding-top: 5px;; padding-bottom: 5px;">
<span onClick="getElementById('sokF').style.display='none', getElementById('bottomA').style.display='none', getElementById('bottomV').style.display='', getElementById('Vsok').style.display=''" class="link_sm">D&ouml;lj s&ouml;kformul&auml;r</span>
</div>

<div style="width: 100%; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 80px;" class="fontS80">
<fieldset style="border: 1px solid Grey; display:inline;"><legend class="small">Fysisk</legend> 
<div class="fl30">&nbsp;F&ouml;rnamn:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60" name="<%= PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_SEARCH_FORNAMN %>" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="fl30">&nbsp;Efternamn:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60" name="<%= PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_SEARCH_EFTERNAMN %>" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')"></div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset style="border: 1px solid Grey; display:inline;"><legend class="small">Juridisk</legend> 
<div class="fl30">&nbsp;F&ouml;retag:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60" name="<%= PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_SEARCH_FORETAG %>" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="fl30">&nbsp;Organisationsnummer:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60" name="<%= PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_SEARCH_ORGNUMMER %>" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')"></div>
</fieldset> <br><br>

<!-- <div class="fl30">Attention, c/o etc.:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="fl30">Postadress:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="fl30">Postnummer:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="30"></div>
<div class="clear"></div> -->

<div class="fl30">Postort:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="40" name="<%= PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_SEARCH_POSTORT %>" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="fl30">Land:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="2" name="<%= PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_SEARCH_LANDKOD %>" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')">&nbsp;
                    <select name="<%= PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_SEARCH_LAND %>" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')">
                        <option value="1" SELECTED></option>
                        <option value="2"></option>
                        <option value="3"></option>
                        <option value="4"></option>
                        <option value="5">---------------------------------</option>
</select></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<!-- <div class="fl30">Region:</div>
<div class="fl20"><select name="">
                        <option value="1" SELECTED></option>
                        <option value="2"></option>
                        <option value="3"></option>
                        <option value="4"></option>
                        <option value="5">-----------------------------------------------</option>
</select></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="fl30">Tel:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="40"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="fl30">Fax:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="40"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="fl30">E-post:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
 -->
<div class="fl50">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="fl5"><input type="button" value="Rensa"></div>
<div class="fl10"><input type="button" value="  S&ouml;k  " onclick="javascript:doSubmit('Namnsokning', 'search')"></div>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

</div>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" align="center">
<tr>    
    <td><h3>Sökresultat:</h3></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td colspan="4">En massa text <span class="link">Hj&auml;lp!</span> </td>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td><input type="button" value="Visa alla"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="smallb">
    <td>Antal &auml;renden: 527</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Visa &auml;renden: &#60;&#60; 1-200 201-400 401-527 &#62;&#62; </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="sortable" id="unique_id">
<tr>
    <th class="thkant">F&ouml;rnamn</th>
    <th class="thkant">Efternamn</th>
    <th class="thkant">Adress</th>
    <th class="thkant">Postnr</th>
    <th class="thkant">Postort</th>
    <th class="thkant">Region</th>
    <th class="thkant">Land</th>
    <th class="thkant">Telefonnummer</th>
</tr>

<%
    for(int i=0; i<apc.getSessionData().getNamnsokningLista().size(); i++) {

        PersonInfo person = (PersonInfo)apc.getSessionData().getNamnsokningLista().get(i);
        if(i%2==0) {
%>
<tr class="g1" onmouseover="javascript:setStoreStyle(this)"; onmouseout="javascript:getStoreStyle(this)" onclick="javascript:doSubmitWithModifierAndIndex('Grunduppgifter','editSearchPerson', '', '<%= person.getPersonId() %>')" style="cursor:pointer;">
<%
        } else {
%>
<tr class="g2"onmouseover="javascript:setStoreStyle(this)"; onmouseout="javascript:getStoreStyle(this)" onclick="javascript:doSubmitWithModifierAndIndex('Grunduppgifter','editSearchPerson', '', '<%= person.getPersonId() %>')" style="cursor:pointer;">
<%
        } 
%>
    <td><%= person.getFornamn() %></td>
    <td><%= person.getEfternamn() %></td>
    <td><%= person.getPostadress() %></td>
    <td><%= person.getPostnr() %></td>
    <td><%= person.getPostort() %></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= person.getLandKod() %></td>
    <td><%= person.getTelefon() %></td> 
</tr>
<%
}
%>
</table>


<div id="bottomV">
<table width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="left"><input type="button" id="visaknapp" value="Visa" disabled style="width:150px;" onClick="getElementById('sokR').style.display='', getElementById('bottomA').style.display='', getElementById('bottomV').style.display='none', getElementById('Vsok').style.display='', getElementById('sokF').style.display='none'"></td>
<td align="right"><input type="button" value="Avbryt" style="width:150px;" class="checkmargin"><input type="button" value="Infoga" disabled style="width:150px;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="bottomA" style="display: none">
<table width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="left"><input type="button" value="&Auml;ndra i register" style="width:150px;"></td>
<td align="right"><input type="button" value="Avbryt" style="width:150px;" class="checkmargin"><input type="button" value="Infoga" style="width:150px;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

but nothing appears. I suspected some badly formatted DIV or other HTML error. checked all output with W3C and there are some error but all DIVs and closed and there were no other relevant HTML error that I could see. What would you think is the reason that my popups won't display? Can you help me fix it?

Thanks

### Update

The complete HTMl source is pasted here http://pastebin.com/uEafLVBd

Comment: Whad did you mean with your words "open a popup"? Did you mean open a div that apperas over the other elelemnts or an normal popup?
By the way, you forgot to add 'document' at "getElementById('popupF')"

Comment: Open a div that appears over the other elements. I added the 'document' to the code but the div still won't render. Thanks for the help...

Comment: Can you post the full html source code that the brwoser received instead of source code with java code? At first view your code makes senses.

Comment: sure but the source was too long to fit here so I posted it here http://pastebin.com/uEafLVBd

Comment: Uhm I think your code is incomplete. My Firefox complains, that the element "popupF" does not exists. Is that correct?

Comment: @reporter I've pasted the JSp code here http://pastebin.com/gQ4GSyFc

Comment: Thanks for posting it. As Brett Smith alerady mentioned we need just the pure rendered HTML source code. We don't know whats going on in the background. The first post was good but only incomplete.

Comment: @reporter I'll post the HTML a.s.a.p. still investigating what causes my nullpointerexception that makes the DIV not rendering. I'm also considering making these popups with JQuery instead that would produce a "real" popup instead of just a DIV over the other element. What do you think of that solution instead? It would be less complex and might reduce code duplication since I need to add pagination to about 8 popups and it can be advantageous not having to load everything at one and a single load for one page which loads all the popups and just hides'em, and instead use JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
document.getElementById('popupF').style.display='block'
```

instead of `getElementById('popupF').style.display=''`

http://jsfiddle.net/j5mUj/5/

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and it still didn't work for me. Maybe I must remake my component from scratch now that it is broken.

Comment: as a side note in the html you posted I can't actually find an element with the id popupF - just checking you haven't accidentally renamed it?

Comment: have you checked the error console from Firefox, Chrome or Safari? Any javascript errors will occure?

Comment: @Brett Smith My mistake, I posted the wrong code block, I updated the quetsion with the right code. I have some validation error in my HTML but it doesn't seem relevant for fixing this. I could maybe try rebuild everything but there are several buttons for these components and best would be if I could get back to where it was working since the code used to work and my update broke it.

Comment: I updated jsfiddle with the actual code and it works fine if I replace a couple of the asp blocks, it would be great to see the rendered source code http://jsfiddle.net/j5mUj/6/

Comment: @reporter I'll check what's going on with firebug but this use case is supposed to work for internet explorer only and it's quite tricky to debug a div that won't render. Thanks for the help.

Comment: only other thing I can see  - <div id="bottomA" style="display: none"> isn't closed in your example code - if this is the case in the actual code then your closing tag for the popup is actually closing div bottomA and popupF is never being closed.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz again in the source code at http://pastebin.com/uEafLVBd there is no popupF it is called popupSokNamn and along with popupSokNamn2,popupI popupP and sokF (along with one other div that doesn't have an id <div style="width: 100%; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 80px;" class="fontS80">) these divs have not been closed. there also appears to be a second html document rendered at the bottom (title Pandora - Tekniskt fel)

Comment: There was a nullpointerexception that made the page not render properly. I've pasted the JSP code here http://pastebin.com/gQ4GSyFc

Comment: really need to post the rendered source code as opposed to the page behind at the moment I don't know what's going on in the background  of the includes.
one thing I did notice is line 298
<input type="checkbox" id="ing_kan_ej" "value="" onclick='toggleDates(this);'> the "value="" probably isn't healthy

Comment: @Brett Smith Yes there are errors on the page and it is too complex. I'm considering doing Jquery popups instead and rewriting this with JQuery popups instead of divs rendering on top of page. I've been troubleshooting this for days currently having a nullpointerexception which makes one of the DIVs not rendering so I can't even troubleshoot it before I've fixed the nullpointer. I might try both way same time, doing one popup with JQuery and keeping one DIV in the meantime so see if I can resolve the problem. The DIVs used to work and then I did some update the broke'em.

Comment: best of luck - sorry I couldn't give you a solution